# HTML and XML Parsing in Fortran

Tags: math, fortran, ascii, fortran95

I am studying mathematical computation and I am completely stuck on this task! I don't even know how to go about starting it!

**Write a program in Fortran that can *parse* a single line of well-formed HTML or XML markup so that it takes input on a single line (guaranteed to not exceed 80 characters in total) like

-lots of lovely text
where

- tag might be anything from 1 to 37 ASCII characters and will not contain spaces
- text could contain spaces and be anything from 1 to 73 characters in length
  so that the program outputs one of  two  lines:

  1. tag : text    if the two occurrences of tag match inside <...> and
  2. syntax error  if anything else is input.

Any help is hugely appreciated !**

Comment: what kind of sadist sets text parsing HW in Fortran?

Comment: I assume your class has provided some reference material for this problem. What ideas do you have thus far? If you share some work, people will be more than happy to critique and to advise on direction. I am pretty sure no one will do the assignment and it will  probably be flagged as it stands now.

Comment: This is my problem exactly, im not sure of how to start..

Comment: Sounds like a fun HW to me.

Comment: FORTRAN 77 and earlier were poor at strings.  Fortran >=95 has a very useful collection of intrinsic procedures and functions.  I suggest studying the intrinsics (e.g., the chapter in the gfortran manual) and thinking about how you can use them.

Comment: Did you study at least some basics of parsing?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of intrinsic functions for working with strings that may be helpful.

- `result = index(string, substring)` - returns the position of the start of the first occurrence of string substring as a substring in string, counting from one. (Fortran 77)
- `result = scan(string, set)` - scans a string for any of the characters in a set of characters. (Fortran 95)
- `result = verify(string, set)` - verifies that all the characters in a string are present in a set. (Fortran 95)

There are a few user-contributed [string tokenization functions on the Fortran Wiki](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/String+tokenization) that might be helpful:
`delim`, `strtok`, and `find_field`.  Also, [FLIBS](http://flibs.sourceforge.net/) includes some string manipulation and tokenization routines that might be useful as examples.

Finally, there are a number of existing open-source XML parsers written in Fortran: [xmlf90](http://fisica.ehu.es/ag/xml/) and [xml-fortran](http://xml-fortran.sourceforge.net/).  Looking at the source code for these libraries should be helpful.